# How to create a local group and add an active directory user to it in WiX

Tags: active-directory, wix

I am trying to create a new local group and then add the currently logged in Active Directory user to that group during an install through WiX.

I have the 2 parts working, but not at the same time... So I can create a group using the [Wix UserPrivileges Extension](http://dblock.github.com/msiext/) like so:

```
<Component Id="LocalSQLAdminGroupComponent" Guid="MYGUID" KeyPath="yes">
            <userPrivileges:LocalGroup Id="LocalSQLAdminsGroupCreate" Name="LocalSQLAdmins" 
                                       Description="Members of this group are designated as sql admins for the ISFS SQL Express instance." 
                                       CheckIfExists="yes" 
                                       CreateOnInstall="yes" 
                                       />
```

But when I add this to add a user to the group from AD (why I cant use the userPriviledges:User element since it only works for local users), the installer errors because the group hasn't been created before the GroupRef tries to assign the User to the Group.

```
<util:Group Id="LocalSQLAdminsGroup" Name="LocalSQLAdmins"/>
...
<util:User Id="ADUser" Domain="[%USERDOMAIN]" Name="[%USERNAME]">
   <util:GroupRef Id="LocalSQLAdminsGroup"/>
</util:User>
```

Is there a way that I can ensure that the Group gets created before the GroupRef tries to add it to the group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work, but you can try it out.

The `<userPrivileges:LocalGroup>` element results in a custom action scheduled deferred somewhere in [`InstallExecuteSequence`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_installexecutesequence.htm). As far as I can see, it is called `CreateLocalGroups_Deferred`. The similar way, the `<util:User>` element results in a custom action called `CreateUser`.

You should try to schedule `CreateUser` custom action after `CreateLocalGroups_Deferred` custom action in `InstallExecuteSequence` table. You can do this with the `Before`, `After` and `Sequence` attributes of the [`<Custom>`](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_custom.htm) element.

I might be wrong with the exact names above, but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this tip got me on the right track.  Here was my final solution (CreateLocalGroups_Deferred may have worked as well): `<Custom Action='ConfigureUsers' After='AddLocalGroupMembers_Deferred'/>`